# BJT: definition of "edge of saturation"

Tags: transistors, bjt, switching, semiconductors

The book Sedra/Smith (Microelectronic circuits) tells in chapter 5 the following:

[image]

My question: I found no statement on why the EOS is defined by the point where vc < (vb - 0.4V).

Seems like other books just define saturation at where vc < vb, and I even saw vc < (vb-0.7V) somewhere else.

Is the 0.4 volts just some value in the region between 0 and 0.7V of forward bias of the CB diode?

Comment: Quote, from the book  "For a PN junction, we know that a PN junction does not effectively become forward biased until the forward voltage across it exceeds approximately 0.4V. If follows that we can maintain active-mode operation of an NPN transistor for a negative Vcb down to approximately -0.4V ".

Comment: Oh damn, I did not stumble across that. Can you tell me the chapter where this is stated?

Comment: @Junius Look underneath the section called "DEVICE STRUCTURE AND PHYSICAL OPERATION", likely in Chapter 5, nearer to 5.1.4? May depend upon your edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with practical teaching vs theoretical, I suppose. For Silicon PN junctions, pretty much anything below a forward-biased magnitude of \$400\:\text{mV}\$ produces currents that are typically less than \$1\:\mu\text{A}\$. (You can work this out using the Shockley diode equation and a couple of DC parameters for it.) So for many practical circuits, the BC junction must be forward-biased by more than \$400\:\text{mV}\$ to produce a meaningful effect. However, technically, there is ***some*** forward-biased current even at a forward-biased voltage difference of
\$200\:\text{mV}\$ (and less.) So, if you want to *get technical* about it then saturation begins when the BC junction is forward-biased, at all. It's just that the effect isn't enough to worry about in most cases.

Where you draw the line will depend upon whom you are speaking to and the subject you are discussing. If you are discussing the impact on active-mode \$\beta\$, then you probably won't notice an effect on it until the  forward-biased voltage difference is
\$\ge 400\:\text{mV}\$. So the DC biasing point won't be impacted much, either. So the operating mode of the BJT is still, for all intents, the same. Yet, from a more technical standpoint, the BJT is moving out of active-mode behavior and towards conditions that will look increasing like saturation behavior. And that fact may also be important to recognize and anticipate, should it "get worse."

In a CE stage design without the application of global NFB, I would tend towards making sure that the BJT's BC junction is always reverse-biased through-out its range of behavior over signal, sufficiently so that the **CE** voltage difference magnitude is \$\ge 2\:\text{V}\$. Because it's "healthier" to make sure you reserve some margin. (The linearity of active mode, assuming the local NFB due to an emitter resistor, starts to deteriorate the more you pare this margin, for example.)

Answer (score 4):

The 0.4 V value is not so much a definition but an observation.

This is from onsemi's [BC547 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc546-d.pdf):

[image: BC547 collector saturation region]

In the active region, the curve is almost vertical; in the saturation region, the curve is almost horizontal; and there is a region in between.

The exact value of V<sub>CE</sub> where the saturation region begins varies, and is different for other transistors.

When you need the transistor to output a certain voltage (e.g., in an analog amplifier), you want it to be in the active region; when you need to use the transistor as a switch, you want to minimize the voltage drop and for the transistor to be in the saturation region. In both cases, you want to stay away from the knee of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of device properties, and a wave of the hand.

As seen in the other answers, Vce can only go so low.  For most modern devices, 0.4V is a reasonable guess, and that's basically all the significance of that figure.  The actual value can be 20mV or less, or several V for very old types (e.g. original hometaxial 2N3055s) or high voltage types (500V+).

We can define saturation in other ways.  Note that, as Vce falls, hFE also falls.  Eventually, no matter how much more Ib you put in, Vce doesn't fall further (indeed eventually it begins to rise).  Here again, the threshold is arbitrary, though we get some guidance from the datasheet: most use hFE(sat) = 10, and give curves of Vce(sat) and Vbe(sat) for a range of Ic.  This fact makes switches easy to design: simply choose some "forced" or "saturated" hFE much lower than the linear-mode hFE, and it'll stay saturated up to the design load current, including parameter and temperature variation.

Or by transconductance: note the Ebers-Moll model only applies in the linear range, and fails at low Vce.  This is relevant to amplifiers, where the transconductance is more relevant than hFE for analysis purposes, and obviously, gain falling suddenly is rather important to an amplifier.  I don't know what saturation model is supposed to be used with Ebers-Moll; SPICE for example avoids this entirely by using the more comprehensive Gummel-Poon model.